# why am i appending twice in jtextfield?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I have looked over this code and i don't know what is wrong. I keep getting incorrect outputs when i enter a command (any input). Please look at the bottom part of my code.

```
public class gui {

    private final static javax.swing.JFrame frame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    private final static javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    public final static javax.swing.JTextArea outtextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea("");
    public final static javax.swing.JTextField intextArea = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.awt.Font font = new java.awt.Font(java.awt.Font.SANS_SERIF, java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 15);
        String command;

        /* Optional */
        frame.setTitle("Console");
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(javax.swing.JRootPane.FRAME); // COMMENT THIS OUT WHEN COMPLETE
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //if exit command, dispose() first
        frame.setBackground(java.awt.Color.BLACK);

        /* size */
        frame.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0b001011010100,0b000110000100));
        frame.setLocation(0,0);
        frame.setExtendedState(javax.swing.JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        /* Sets panel */
        panel.setBackground(java.awt.Color.PINK); // if sees pink, has error
        panel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        panel.setSize(frame.getWidth(),frame.getHeight());

        /* Sets text area */
        //javax.swing.JScrollPane inscrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(intextArea);
        intextArea.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);
        intextArea.setFont(font);
        intextArea.setBackground(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
        intextArea.setForeground(java.awt.Color.GREEN);
        intextArea.setFocusable(true);

        javax.swing.JScrollPane outscrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(outtextArea);
        outtextArea.setRows(10);
        outtextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        outtextArea.setFont(font);
        outtextArea.setBackground(java.awt.Color.BLUE);
        outtextArea.setForeground(java.awt.Color.GREEN);
        outtextArea.setEditable(false);

        /* Sets all necessary components */
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(outscrollPane,java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
       // panel.add(inscrollPane,java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.add(intextArea,java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        /* Adjusts components */
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //every time a command is entered, it is sent to handler and 
        //textbox should be cleared

// THIS BELOW IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES/////////////////////////////
        boolean keepGoing=true;
        while(keepGoing){
            command = intextArea.getText();
            String refactored;
            if(entering_a_command(command) && !command.equals("exit")){
                refactored=command.substring(0,command.length()-1);
                outtextArea.append(refactored+"\n");
                intextArea.setText("");
            }
            else if(!command.equals("exit")){//no need to read before submission
                outtextArea.append("");
                command=intextArea.getText();
            }
            else{
                outtextArea.append("EXITING\n");
                keepGoing=false;
            }
        }

    }
    /*
        Method is strictly for entering user input at appropriate time
    */
    private static boolean entering_a_command(String temp){
        //handler.print(temp);
        return temp.contains("="); //key to submit user input
    }
}
```

My input:

- 12345=
- 123456=
- This is hell=
- This is hello=

My EXPECTED output:

- 12345
- 123456
- This is hell
- This is hello

My ACTUAL output:

- 12345
- 12345
- This is hell
- This is hell

My problem:
When i enter an input the first time, it all checks out. When i enter an input the second time, an input that has greater length than the first, it is automatically submitted just as if i had pressed the trigger key (=).

The input box is the black box in the bottom. To submit an input, press '='

Comment: We're not going to run your code. You need to provide us the _exact_ input and _exact_ expected output. As well as a clear statement of the issue.

Comment: Is this some part of an event listener? You need to show a bigger part of your program - we certainly can't reproduce it without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - mind that you keep it minimal.

Comment: I have listened to your comments, please help me.

Comment: I've run your code, but can't get it to do *anything* in the top part. It doesn't help that it you're accessing a UI control in a non-UI thread... you should be using event handlers for this...

Comment: type in the black part. the top part is for output only. non editable @JonSkeet.

Comment: how does this work. I tried to run the code. It get compiled and run but i dnt understand what is that

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne it takes input through the black box and outputs through the blue box.

Comment: i just typ in black box but nothing seems to happen

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne To submit an input, press '=', as aforementioned

Comment: when i type something and press = it appeared on blue box without duplicating'

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne please re-read the whole question.

Comment: Okay, with the `=` part, it seems to work for me. If it's not working for you, I suspect that's due to the threading issues. You should read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: @JonSkeet my problem isn't the = part. it's the duplication of output. if i enter '1234' and press =, output is '1234'. then when i enter '12345', the code acts like i entered '1234' and presses '=', even when i didn't.

Comment: Did you read my comment fully? When I hit `=`, I don't see the problem you're seeing. The problem is almost certainly with the way you're using threads. You should be adding an event listener instead of looping in another thread and accessing UI elements from it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've read your comment carefully. I believe i haven't explained well enough of my problem. My problem is that somewhere in my code, it is taking my first input's length, waiting until i type something with the same length +1, and automatically appends() without me giving the order.

Comment: No, you've explained what you're seeing several times. I've likewise explained what's wrong: you're accessing UI elements from the wrong thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're abusing the threading model. You shouldn't be accessing UI components in a thread other than the UI thread - and having a tight loop like this is pretty much *always* a bad idea. You should read about the [Swing threading model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). From that tutorial:

> Swing event handling code runs on a special thread known as the event dispatch thread. Most code that invokes Swing methods also runs on this thread. This is necessary because most Swing object methods are not "thread safe": invoking them from multiple threads risks thread interference or memory consistency errors.

Instead, you should add an event listener to your text area. There are *loads* of options here, none of which is obviously ideal, unfortunately. Adding a key listener and handling `keyTyped` sounds good - but you get the event *before* the key ends up in the text area, which isn't ideal. Adding a document listener is a nice abstraction in that then it doesn't matter how the text is changed (e.g. programmatically) - but you can't mutate the document within a listener, so you can't clear it.

As a starting point, adding a key listener and handling `keyReleased` works well at least for the simple case. Get rid of your current loop (and the unconventionally named `entering_a_command` method) and replace them with:

```
intextArea.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
    @Override public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
        String command = intextArea.getText();
        if (!command.contains("=")) {
            return;
        }

        command = command.substring(0, command.length() - 1);
        if (command.equals("exit")) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();
            return;
        }
        outtextArea.append(command + "\n");
        intextArea.setText("");
    }
});
```

Comment: I know i may sound ignorant as i am a beginner still, but i am not stupid to know when i see logic. So thank you for clearly showing me a better alternative to my problem. I've been looking how to implement a listener, but i've never gotten it down right, until now.

Comment: should be listening from model - (Plaint/Abstract)Document by using [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) instead of KeyListener (Pressed/Realeased only one char), DocumentListener firing an event if text (more than one char) is entered from e.g. ClipBoard

Comment: @mKorbel: I explained in the answer why that's a pain - you can't mutate the document within a listener.

Comment: (Plaint/Abstract)Document is name of model for JTextComponents, for event there is as listener - DocumentListener/Filter, KeyListener is last property for Swing, is low_level, and not possible to catch (maybe more) half KeyEvents from KeyBoard

Comment: @mKorbel: Sorry, I don't understand your comment at all. If you have a cleaner solution than this, please add it as a new answer. I suspect it can be done with `DocumentListener` by deferring the reset of `intextArea`, but that's ugly in itself :(